# Quick, portable way to launch perl script on Mac (equiv. to Batch on Win)

Tags: perl, bash, batch-file, applescript

I have a perl script shared in a repository with several users across Mac and Windows machines. It performs its work on files located in the folder with it. Because I run it frequently and because some users don't even know what a command line is, I created a batch file in the directory to make it easy to launch. Because some paths will differ, I made it portable:

```
    ::figure out your directory path
    pushd %~dp0
    :: launch the script
    perl my_perl_script.pl
    popd
```

The batch works perfectly on Windows and I put it in each project folder with each perl script and tell my users to just "double-click that thingy."

How can I do the same on Mac? I don't know much about bash, and I can't figure out how to

1) Have a bash file figure out its directory path, and
   2) Make the bash a simple "double-click that thingy" executable for my Mac users.

Would a simple Applescript be better (I don't really know Applescript either...)

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Thanks, dj bazzie wazzie. I didn't want to run both a bash and applescript to get my perl to run, but I did use your first line to get an applescript that works perfectly for me.

```
    set currentWorkingDirectory to do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me) 
    tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script "cd " & currentWorkingDirectory
    do script "perl xml2epub_3689_7KeysSpWellness.pl" in currentTab 
    end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

With AppleScript you have the ability run a shell command. Let's say your bash file is located next to the script and is named maintenance.sh your script would look something like this

```
set currentWorkingDirectory to do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me)
do shell script quoted form of (currentWorkingDirectory & "/maintenance.sh")
```

EDIT: (I can't comment your post so I change my post)
For such a simple command as yours you don't need the terminal application. I can understand that a working application is enough but for a much smoother script I would put that command into a do shell script. So the code for your per command would be something like this

```
set currentWorkingDirectory to do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me)
do shell script "perl " & quoted form of (currentWorkingDirectory & "/xml2epub_3689_7KeysSpWellness.pl")
```